# Shared utils functions for testing with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have some utils functions that I'm using among various Jest tests, for example a function like this, for mocking a fetch response:

```js
export const mockFetchJsonResponse = (data) => {
    ok: () => true,
    json: () => data
};
```

I would like to share those functions in a way that I can import them and reuse among my tests. For example:

```js
// Some .spec.jsx file
// ...
import {mockFetchJsonResponse} from 'some/path/to/shared/tests/utils.jsx'

// Then I can use mockFetchJsonResponse inside this test
// ...
```

Where should I place such common utils functions?

My project folder looks like this:

```
components/
    CompOne/
        __tests__
        index.jsx
    CompTwo/
        __tests__
        ...
utils/
    __tests__
    http.js
    user.js
    ...
```

Should I place them inside the `utils` folder together with other utils functions that I use for my project? Then should I write unit tests also for these functions?

Answer (score 72):

There is an ability to expose helpers as global functions without any need to import modules explicitly.

1. Jest allows to configure some files will be run before every test file executed through [`setupFiles`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#setupfiles-array) configuration option
2. Also Jest provides [`global`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globals-object) object that you can modify and everything you put there will be available in your tests.

#### Example

package.json:

```
"jest": {
    "setupFiles": ["helpers.js"]
}
```

helpers.js:

```
global.mockFetchJsonResponse = (data) => {
    ok: () => true,
    json: () => data
};
```

somecomponent.test.js:

```
mockFetchJsonResponse(); // look mom, I can call this like say expect()!
```

#### With TypeScript

TypeScript will complain with `cannot find name 'mockFetchJsonResponse'`. You can fix that by adding a declaration file:

helpers.d.ts:

```
declare function mockFetchJsonResponse(data: any): any;
```

Create a new `tsconfig.test.json` file and add that file to the `files` section and extend your main tsconfig:

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "files": ["./.jest/helpers.d.ts"]
}
```

In your `jest.config.js` file, add a new global setup for `ts-jest` to have jest use your new tsconfig file:

```
// ...
globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
         tsconfig: "tsconfig.test.json"
    }
}
// ...
```

---

Sure it does not answer you direct question "where to put the files" but it's anyway up to you. You just need specify those files in `setupFiles` section. Since there is no `import` needed in tests it does not really matter.

As for testing test helpers I'm not sure. See it's part of testing infrastructure like spec file itself. And we don't write tests for tests or it would never stop. Sure, it's up to you - say if logic behind is really-really complex and hard to follow. But if helper provides too complex/complicated logic it would lead to tests themselves be impossible to understand, do you agree?

kudos to that [article on testing compoentns with intl](https://blog.sapegin.me/all/react-intl-jest-enzyme). Have never dealt with `globals` in jest before.

Comment: ESLint claims on `no-undef` when I use such functions. So I think its better just to use `import`,

Comment: @AndreySemakin, I think it's fine for you to choose to use import, but I'm not sure I'd say that it's unequivocally *better*.  I think whatever reduces the friction to writing good clean tests and improves developer ergonomics is ultimately what defines *better*.  That always depends on the project and the team.  Personally, I tend to keep my linter settings more relaxed for test files than I do for application code.  I also don't mind defining globals in a `.d.ts` file either.

Comment: @D.Patrick completely makes sense. As for me I prefer to keep my linter settings as strict as possible even in test files to ensure that I don't use my own code in wrong way :) That's why I prefer to use import over defining globals using Jest.

Comment: This is what I was looking for and very nice touch with the .ts requirement.

Comment: @Hubro I suppose this answer gets votes mostly because of your edit with part about Typescript.

Comment: @AndreySemakin For what it's worth, you can tell ESLint about the globals in your project to resolve this.

Answer (score 15):

TL;DR; create a `/__utils__/` and update [testPathIgnorePatterns](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testpathignorepatterns-arraystring)

Full answer:

Here's just a suggestion:

```
testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/__fixtures__/', '/__utils__/'],
```

I use `/__tests__/` for the tests and within it sometimes I need to add a folder with data that will be used by those tests, so I use `/__fixtures__/` folder.

Likewise, when I have a shared logic across tests, I place them at `/__utils__/` folder (also within `/__tests__/`)

For more details, please read more about [testPathIgnorePatterns](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testpathignorepatterns-arraystring)

Answer (score 8):

Another approach is by having a test directory and moving helpers on it.

```
src/
  components/
  utils/
  ...
test/
  testHelpers.js
```

Then on the test:

```
// src/components/MyComponent.spec.js
import { helperFn } from '../../test/testHelpers';
```

Benefits:

- Be explicit of where the function is coming from
- Separate helpers that need to be tested from those that do not ¹

Drawbacks:

- The `test` directory might look silly by containing just a helper file
- AFAIK this approach is no where specified on official documentation

Looks like [GitLab is implementing](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/tree/master/spec/frontend/helpers) this approach on their RoR project.

¹ no matter which approach you take, please don't test the test helpers. If the helper fails then your test must fail too. Otherwise your helper is not helping at all.

Comment: The issue is that these functions will be packaged unlike files into __tests__ folders.