# Disabling the 'Your test suite must contain at least one test' rule in Jest

Tags: jestjs

Jest has a *'Your test suite must contain at least one test.'* rule. It complains that if I have a file that isn't a test suite it cannot exist in the `__test__/` directory that I have created (see below). This basically means everything in that folder (including the subfolders) must be a test suite.

How do I get around this? I really want to store my mock data objects with my test suites.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7280#issuecomment-433409841

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shared utils functions for testing with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50411719/shared-utils-functions-for-testing-with-jest)

Answer (score 14):

The [default glob patterns](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testmatch-array-string) that `Jest` uses to find test files are

`[ "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)", "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)" ]`

In other words...

> By default it looks for `.js`, `.jsx`, `.ts` and `.tsx` files inside of `__tests__` folders, as well as any files with a suffix of `.test` or `.spec` (e.g. `Component.test.js` or `Component.spec.js`). It will also find files called `test.js` or `spec.js`.

Because `mockData.js` is in a subdirectory of `__tests__` it is being found by the default glob patterns and assumed to be a test.

To keep `Jest` from treating `mockData.js` as a test you can change the glob patterns `Jest` uses to find tests with the [`testMatch`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testmatch-arraystring) configuration option, or to use regular expressions instead of glob patterns use [`testRegex`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testregex-string--arraystring).

Comment: To complete this answer: the following config in your `package.json` (see `jest` section) will do the trick: `"testMatch": [ "**/?(*.)+(test).[jt]s?(x)" ]`.

Answer (score 14):

Calling [skip](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testskipname-fn) in your test utility file will suppress that rule violation:

```
test.skip('Workaround', () => 1)
```

Adding this for completeness. Brian's `testMatch`/`testRegex` solution seems more clean to me.

Comment: good simple answer, but had to use `test.skip('Workaround', () => {})` in TS to get it to compile